# Sci fi Novel about boys being stuck in VR

Tags: story-identification, books

I read this book when I was young, in middle school. I think I read the book around 2005 but the book felt a bit old so possibly an 80s/90s book? The book didn't have any pictures, it wasn't a long book either

Cover was maybe a boy wearing some kind of VR headset, felt very video game oriented about two boys being trapped in the same VR space. They couldn't get out unless they defeated the bosses/conquered the levels? I remembered 2 quotes from the book that were something along the lines of:

"To defeat the boss we need to destroy his heart, not his physical heart but his gold" (I believe this was said in the fight with the last boss)

"Give me an axe and I'll show the computer what I want" (he says this after defeating the last boss and I think jokingly in response to being asked by the other boy if they should go again)

I have no other information to give on this book, at this point I'm starting to go crazy trying to figure out if it really exists, I remember it being very descriptive and captivating to read

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think you're talking about [*Rodomonte's Revenge*](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?1845926) (1994) by Gary Paulsen.  It is very short, just 82 pages.

Quoting the blurb from [the publisher's website](https://www.rhcbooks.com/books/128366/rodomontes-revenge-by-gary-paulsen):

> *As Brett watched, one hand slipped loose, then the other. Tom dropped, screaming, into the flames. His body, all red and bubbled, boiled up once to the surface, then was gone*.
> PLAYER ONE HAS ONE LIFE REMAINING. GAME CONTINUES.
>
> Flaming fire rivers. Divebombing buzz-bugs. A cruel king waiting to do battle in his computer-generated castle. Video game whizzes Brett Wilder and Tom Houston think that new virtual reality game *Rodomonte’s Revenge* is awesome-until it takes over their minds. Then the game playing becomes dangerously real, and one wrong move could be the last.

[image: Brett and Tom, wearing white helmets, gauntlets, and boots, wield a sword and energy gun against a giant fly]

Brett Wilder and Tom Houston are friends who start playing a brand new virtual-reality videogame called *Rodomonte's Revenge*.  They play at an arcade in town, and have to take turns with other people to play; they play the game several times, becoming superficially familiar with it, before anything strange happens.

The game invades their minds and it can hurt and even kill them:

> "It's worse than crazy," Willie said. "Rodomonte's Revenge is a part of your minds now. If something happens to you when the game takes over—"
>
> "Then it happens to us in real life." Brett shuddered. He didn't want ears like the mangled one he believed Willie had. But there was something even worse than that. **"So if we die in the game—"**
>
> **"Then we die in real life." Tom shuddered, too.**
>
> Willie studied them long and hard. "You're going to play Rodomonte's Revenge again whether you want to or not. This time there won't be any second or third chance. This time you play for real."

One of the quotes you remember:

> Rodomonte had said that **to kill a king, they had to destroy his heart, but he wasn't talking about his physical heart**, he was talking about what was most important to him.  A greedy king's heart was in his treasure.

The other quote that you recall:

> "The computer is asking if you want to play again."
>
> Tom grunted. "**Give me an ax, and I’ll show that computer what I want.**" He opened and closed his pistol hand, without the pistol, as if he were surprised it was still there. "How long did the game take?"

Comment: Sir I cannot thank you enough, this is definitely it!!!! This book has been on my mind for years.... I'm going to get all of his books and read them. The author has such a way with words I remember this being the first book that really captivated me and I never really considered myself a heavy reader. Thanks again!!